# Scala Random Number Generator Not Producing Unique Random Numbers Between A Range

Tags: scala, random

I have the following code to generate new random numbers

```
val start = 1
val end = 50000000
val rnd = new scala.util.Random

for (i < 1 to 25000000){
  val rnum = start + rnd.nextInt((end - start) + 1)

...
}
```

But this is producing duplicate random numbers now and again. Is this a bug or have I done something stupid?

Comment: Random number generators will produce the same values now and again. If they didn't, they wouldn't be as random as you could more easily guess what values will be produced as time goes on. You'll need to manually ensure duplicates aren't produced if you want that restriction.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem and https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0167637786900921.  You have 50M "days" in your year, so the probability of duplicates is better than 99% by the time you have generated as few as 21000 (3*sqrt(50M)) values.

Comment: Consider using [shuffle](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.8/scala/util/Random.html#shuffle[T,CC[X]%3C:TraversableOnce[X]](xs:CC[T])(implicitbf:scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[CC[T],T,CC[T]]):CC[T]) if you want to generate a collection of non-duplicated numbers.  e.g. `scala.util.Random.shuffle(1 to 20)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't worry, this is not a bug, and you have not done anything stupid. However you have missed the fact that **a sequence of random numbers can contain duplicates**.

The reasons are explained in the comments.

The problem is that humans don't have a good instinctive understanding of random numbers. If you ask people to write a series of digits they are very unlikely to repeat a digit, even though this should happen 10% of the time. If you ask people to write down 5 random digits they are unlikely to use the same digit twice, even though this should happen 70% of the time.

Answer (score 1):

There is no bug. It selects randomly so chances are there that same element would be picked.
I prefer using the shuffle function of List.

```
val list = (1 to 100).toList

scala.util.Random.shuffle(list).take(1)
```

But creating a list of big number won't be an effective solution. You can use the following way to generate a random number.

```
val seed = new java.util.Date().hashCode
val rand = new scala.util.Random(seed)
val someNum = rand.nextInt
```

Comment: @Tim There is no bug. I have updated the answer. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Like your way to shuffle list to get fixed number of distinct random numbers. It suits my needs well.